# ARM L2 Cache access count differs when stepping though code

Tags: performance, caching, arm

I am using OpenOCD to run a program on an embedded board with an ARM Cortex-A9 (a Zynq-7010; I'm using a single core running a baremetal program).

I would like to be able to figure out if each memory access results in a cache hit or a cache miss. The L2 Cache Controller, an L2C-310, provides two counters which I have configured to count Data Read Hits and Data Read Lookups (which result in either a hit or a miss).

The problem is that I get different results when I execute the program without stopping compared to when I execute the program and step through each line. My specific question is: Why is there a difference and is there a way that I can make the output uniform? More generally: Is it possible to determine if a specific line of assembly resulted in a cache hit?

I am controlling OpenOCD using a python script. I am disabling the L1 caches (not shown), turning off pre-fetching, and (I think) turning off the pre-load engine. Here is the code I am running when executing the program without stopping:

```
# A this point, the program has be loaded, and allowed to execute up until the start of the code section I am measuring

telnet = Telnet('127.0.0.1', 4444, 300)

end_addr = 0x100930 # End of code section I am measuing

### 1) Pre-Fetch / Pre-Load stuff ####################
# Turning off the pre-fetch option. Should read, change mask, then write
print('\tSetting pre-fetch option to off\n')
telnet.write('arm mcr 15 0 1 0 1\n')
response = telnet.read_until('arm mcr 15 0 1 0 1\r\n')
response = telnet.read_until('\r>')
print('Response: %s' % (response))

actlr = int(response[:-2])
print('actlr: %d' % (actlr))

actlr = actlr & (~(1 << 2)) # Disable L1 Pre-fetch
actlr = actlr & (~(1))      # Disable TLB / Cache maintenance fwd
print('actlr: %d' % (actlr))

# write to telnet
telnet.write('arm mrc 15 0 1 0 1 ' + str(actlr) + '\n')

telnet.write('arm mcr 15 0 1 0 1\n')
response = telnet.read_until('arm mcr 15 0 1 0 1\r\n')
response = telnet.read_until('\r>')
print('Response: %s' % (response))

print('attempting to pause pre-load engine:')
telnet.write('arm mrc 15 0 11 3 0 0\n')
######################################################

### 2) Enable L2CC counters ##########################
telnet.write('mww 0xF8F02200 0x1\n') # enable counting

# confirm enabled
telnet.write('mdw 0xF8F02200\n')
response = telnet.read_until('mdw 0xF8F02200\r\n')
response = telnet.read_until('\r>')
print('Response should be 1: %s' % (response))

# Counter 0: 0011 to set source to Data Lookup, 01 for increment
telnet.write('mww 0xF8F02208 0xD\n')
# confirm counter 0 settings
telnet.write('mdw 0xF8F02208\n')
response = telnet.read_until('mdw 0xF8F02208\r\n')
response = telnet.read_until('\r>')
print('Response should be 0xD: %s' % (response))

# Counter 1: 0010 to set source to Data Read Hit, 01 for increment
telnet.write('mww 0xF8F02204 0x9\n')
# confirm counter 1 settings
telnet.write('mdw 0xF8F02204\n')
response = telnet.read_until('mdw 0xF8F02204\r\n')
response = telnet.read_until('\r>')
print('Response should be 0x9: %s' % (response))
######################################################

### 3) Different from step mode ######################
print("Setting end tag to 0x%x" % (end_addr))

# Set breakpoint to end of section
telnet.write('bp ' + str(end_addr) + ' 1 hw\n')

telnet.write('resume\n')
response = telnet.read_until('resume\r\n', 1)
response = telnet.read_until('>', 1)

# Allow program to execute
sleep(10)
######################################################

### 4) Check L2CC counters ###########################
# Counter 0: number of data lookups
telnet.write('mdw 0xF8F02210\n')
response = telnet.read_until('mdw 0xF8F02210\r\n')
response = telnet.read_until('\r>')
print('Data Lookups: %s' % (response))

# Counter 1: check number of data read hits
telnet.write('mdw 0xF8F0220C\n')
response = telnet.read_until('mdw 0xF8F0220C\r\n')
response = telnet.read_until('\r>')
print('Data Read Hits: %s' % (response))

system('exit')
```

The results of which are:

```
Data Lookups: 0xf8f02210: 00000660
Data Read Hits: 0xf8f0220c: 000004c2
```

When I run the code by stepping through each instruction, the number of data lookups ends up being the same as the number of read hits... so where did those cache misses go?

Here is the changed code (chunk number 3):

```
### 3) Different from continuous mode ##############
print("Setting end tag to 0x%x" % (end_addr))

cur_addr = step()

# Run until the end tag
while cur_addr != end_addr:
    cur_addr = step()
```

And the `step()` function:

```
# Commands OpenOCD to step the processor forward
# Returns the new pc address
# Sorry for the messy error checking!
def step():
    telnet.write('step\n')
    response = telnet.read_until('step\r\n', 1)
    # print('Step: %s ****' % (response))

    # Skip line of output
    response = telnet.read_until('\n', 1)
    # print('Step: %s ****' % (response))

    # 2nd line has the pc, 4th column
    response = telnet.read_until('\n', 1)
    # print('Step: %s ****' % (response))
    try:
        cur_addr = int(response.strip().split()[3], 16)
    except (ValueError, IndexError) as e:
        print("Error step() on line: ", response)
        print("\tException: ", e)
        countdown = 20
        error = True
        while (countdown > 0):
            countdown = countdown - 1
            response = telnet.read_until('\n', 1)
            #print("Retry on line: ", response)

            if ('cpsr' in response): # TODO: Maybe just read until this anyways?
                print("Found a match.\n")
                cur_addr = int(response.strip().split()[3], 16)
                countdown = 0
                error = False
        if error:
            # try sending again?
            telnet.write('step\n')
            response = telnet.read_until('step\r\n', 1)
            print('Step: %s ****' % (response))

            # Skip line of output
            response = telnet.read_until('\n', 1)
            print('Step: %s ****' % (response))

            # 2nd line has the pc, 4th column
            response = telnet.read_until('\n', 1)

            print("Failed to recover from error? Retried:", response)
            cur_addr = int(response.strip().split()[3], 16) # This line should fail

    response = telnet.read_until('>', 1) # skip remaining

    return cur_addr
```

And the output:

```
Data Lookups: 0xf8f02210: 000004c2
Data Read Hits: 0xf8f0220c: 000004c2
```

Thank you for your time, and I appreciate any help.

Comment: When you step, the memory must be resolved immediately.  Ie, loaded to a register.  If you are loading consecutive locations, then the read may 'burst/buffer' so you won't get the cache hit (2 reads ganged together).  So basically, the difference is probably 'buffer/burst' advantage.  Although depending on your 'stepping'; debug code on the target may cause cache hits.

Comment: I'm not sure that the "burst/buffer" theory matches my results: I see the same number of hits when running continuously vs stepping. And fewer lookups when stepping. Isn't the opposite of what one would expect if moving from bursts to single accesses when stepping?

Comment: See: [Cortex-A9 and L2C](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0246f/CJACBHHB.html).  The concept of stepping being different from running to the memory pipe of the ARM should be apparent?  Of course the values will be different.  Also in your text you have "where did those cache misses go?"  Which seems inconsistent with what you said in the comment above.  I think it is really difficult for anyone to answer your question concretely.  It is probably better to ask on the ARM forum where the chip designers frequent.

Comment: I'm happy to provide more information if it helps. I have spent hours with the docs. I don't see how my misses comment is contradictory... I'm sorry, I'm not trying to be dense, but if this was all obvious to me then I wouldn't be here asking questions.